# Handle iOS touch to emulate mouse for C++ input library

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios

I've got existing cross-platform C++ code to handle mouse-input, with methods like:

```
onMouseDown(x,y,button)
onMouseUp(x,y,button)
onMouseMove(x,y,buttons)
```

I'm porting functionality into a C++ iOS app... using the minimum Objective-C as required. I'd like to handle single-touch gestures to emulate mouse functionality so I can pass parameters into existing methods (as well as adding multitouch).

What would code look like to do this, ideally as a minimal sample app - it's mainly the OBJ-C/C++ interaction that really confuses me?

Comment: As a side-note, any decent C++-biased iOS development tutorials/book recommendations would be gratefully received.

Comment: Looks like you got some good answers below, but one main thing that maybe you don't know is to name the ObjectiveC file .mm and you can then mix C++ and ObjC code in the same file.  Makes this kind of thing really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the good answers. I felt that Jonathon's answer was most specific to the question asked and tracked the touches as a useful bonus, but sqreept's was closer to the bounty request for a complete workable sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I pass multi-touch to C++ code for an OpenGL program (with 1 or 2 fingers):

```
// Set this in your ViewController's init code
[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

// Implement these in ViewController
int touchCount = 0;
UITouch* touch[2];

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{ 
    NSArray* array = [touches allObjects];  
    UITouch* touchTemp; 
    int t;
    int touchedPixel[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i){
        touchTemp = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        if(touchCount >= 2)
            return;

        if(touch[0] == NULL)    
            t = 0;
        else
            t = 1;      
        touch[t] = touchTemp;

        CGPoint touchLoc = [touch[t] locationInView:(EAGLView *)self.view]; 
        ++touchCount;

        touchedPixel[X] = touchLoc.x;
        touchedPixel[Y] = touchLoc.y;
        mainScreen->push(t, touchedPixel);  // mainScreen is a C++ object for GL drawing.
    }
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    NSArray* array = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch* touchTemp; 
    int t;
    int touchedPixel[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i){
        touchTemp = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        for(t = 0; t < 2; ++t){         // Find the matching touch in the array
            if(touchTemp == touch[t])
                break;
        }       
        if(t == 2)                      // Return if touch was not found
            continue;

        CGPoint touchLoc = [touch[t] locationInView:(EAGLView *)self.view]; 

        touchedPixel[X] = touchLoc.x;
        touchedPixel[Y] = touchLoc.y;
        mainScreen->move(t, touchedPixel);
    }
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{ 
    NSArray* array = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch* touchTemp; 
    int t;
    int touchedPixel[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i){
        touchTemp = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        for(t = 0; t < 2; ++t){         // Find the matching touch in the array
            if(touchTemp == touch[t])
                break;
        }       
        if(t == 2)                      // Return if touch was not found
            continue;               

        CGPoint touchLoc = [touch[t] locationInView:(EAGLView *)self.view];

        touch[t] = NULL;
        --touchCount;

        touchedPixel[X] = touchLoc.x;
        touchedPixel[Y] = touchLoc.y;
        mainScreen->release(t, touchedPixel);
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    printf("Touch cancelled\n");
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: I'm interested, can you do it also by listening for drag/press touches?

Comment: Yes, the touchesMoved() is a drag, touchesBegan() is mouseDown, and touchesEnded() is mouseUp.  The touchesCancelled happens when someone puts more than five(?) fingers on a screen, and you lose all touch information.  So, you have to do release there.

Comment: So, this code ensures the touch t is consistent, then the C++ classes decide what to do with it.  Further into the code, all C++ screen classes inherit from my virtual class Touchable, which is either single-touch only or multi-touch capable.

Comment: touchesCancelled happens in other scenarios, too. From what I understand, it just means that something interrupted the touch so that it never completed. Apple's code mentiones holding a phone up to the face as an example. I've found that another subview intercepting the touch can do it, too. In any case, if it happens, and you've done setup with touchesBegan and/or touchesMoved, you need to do cleanup if you get a touchesCancelled event. Each touch object has a lifespan that starts with touchesBegan and ends with touchesEnded or touchesCancelled. The touchesMoved event may not occur.

Answer (score 3):

for this situation I would implement touchesBegan, moved andEnded and forward the call to the c++ mouseDown/Moved/Up code

sample of what I would do:
assumes the code is in the app's viewController!

```
static UITouch *_trackedTouch = nil;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    assert(!_trackedTouch && "no multitouch");

    _trackedTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt = [_trackedTouch locationInView:self.view];
    mouseDown(pt.x,pt.y,0);
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    assert(_trackedTouch && "no touch began");

    if(![touches containsObject:_trackedTouch])
        return;

    CGPoint pt = [_trackedTouch locationInView:self.view];
    mouseMoved(pt.x,pt.y,0);
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    assert(_trackedTouch && "no touch began");

    if(![touches containsObject:_trackedTouch])
        return;

    CGPoint pt = [_trackedTouch locationInView:self.view];
    mouseUp(pt.x,pt.y,0);
}
```

---

about books mhm... maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308106/book-recommendations-for-objective-c-for-ios-development (but the arent C++ biased... objC is based on C. C++ is just something you can use in addition to ObjC but.. knowing C++ only provides limited help with learning ObjC)

Comment: fixed sample, forgot a ! :D

Comment: it's mainly the C++/OBJ-C interop I get confused about to be honest :) And I didn't realise you could track the same touch like this, that's good to know as it fixes one obvious problem.

Answer (score 3):

This works with both singletouch and multitouch use cases. I've written a stub c++ lib called `oldlib` that I'm using in the obj-c files below.

You can pass whatever you need as `button`. My code passes the touch ID. I suppose you'll need to check what your library expects there and change that accordingly.

Here's my code:

oldlib.h

```
#ifndef Quick_oldlib_h
#define Quick_oldlib_h

void onMouseDown(int x,int y,int button);
void onMouseUp(int x,int y,int button);
void onMouseMove(int x,int y,int buttons);

#endif
```

oldlib.cpp

```
#include "oldlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void onMouseDown(int x,int y,int button)
{
    printf("onMouseDown:%d,%d button:%d\n", x, y, button);
}

void onMouseUp(int x,int y,int button)
{
    printf("onMouseUp:%d,%d button:%d\n", x, y, button);
}

void onMouseMove(int x,int y,int button)
{
    printf("onMouseMove:%d,%d button:%d\n", x, y, button);
}
```

QViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

QViewController.mm <- note the MM extension which enables compiling this together with C++ headers

```
#import "QViewController.h"
#include "oldlib.h"

@interface QViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet* active_touches;
@end

@implementation QViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.active_touches = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        [self.active_touches addObject:touch];
        onMouseDown([touch locationInView:self.view].x, [touch locationInView:self.view].y, (int)(__bridge void*)touch);
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        if ([self.active_touches containsObject:touch]) {
            onMouseUp([touch locationInView:self.view].x, [touch locationInView:self.view].y, (int)(__bridge void*)touch);
            [self.active_touches removeObject:touch];
        }
    }
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        if ([self.active_touches containsObject:touch]) {
            onMouseMove([touch locationInView:self.view].x, [touch locationInView:self.view].y, (int)(__bridge void*)touch);
        }
    }
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        [self.active_touches removeObject:touch];
        NSLog(@"cancelled: %@", touch);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll need to implement touch-forwarding, and ensure that the touch you have just detected is consumed by your C++ code, rather than any Cocoa Touch object in the responder chain. For example, inside a view's `touchesBegan:withEvent:` selector, you would include a call to your `onMouseDown(int, int, void*)` method. `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` will have similar logic.

There are a few difficulties though. According to the HIG, `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` should always be implemented when the other `touches*:withEvent:` selectors are implemented, and you will have to include logic to handle that.

The other problem you may encounter is with `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses. I mentioned before that you have to make sure your C++ code consumes the touch. However, if you use gesture recognisers, your whole responder chain can get messed up if you're ALSO implementing the `touches*:WithEvent:` selectors. There are some excellent WWDC videos explaining this. In short though, if your gesture recogniser consumes the touch, it will never be sent to your C++ methods. The simple solution would be to just not use gesture recognisers, but they are by far the easiest way to handle multitouch well.

Which brings us to a final possibility (if you wish to use gesture recognisers). Instead of solely implementing the `touches*:withEvent:` selectors, you could set the action of gesture recognisers to be an Objective-C selector which simply wraps a call to your C++ code. For example a `UITapGestureRecogniser`'s action could be a method called `onTap` which simply calls `onMouseDown(...)`. If you do choose to go down this path, definitely watch the WWDC videos ('11 and '12) where touch handling and the responder chain is explained in more detail.

On the topic of books handling Objective-C++, Apple themselves have removed the page which used to explain the do's and don't's of ObjC++... It is however, available [here, thankfully](http://web.archive.org/web/20090423073703/http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html). The easiest way to handle the cross-over is to implement the bare essentials of the Application Layer in Objective-C and forward all appropriate calls to your C++ engine. Personally I'd program the App Delegate in Pure Objective-C, but once you're into your `ViewController`, you've got free reign.